# What's the best pratice to use tools function with Zend Framework

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I'm currently on a Zend project, i create a controller named `company`, where i created many action. 
Now i want to code some utils function, they will be only used in one action of my controller let's say `nameAction`.

Here is what i did :

```
class CompanyController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function nameAction( $name = null ) {

        function get_inner_html( $node ) {
            // Some code goes here
            return $html;
        }

        function check_if_social_account($url) {
          // Some code goes here
            return $social_account;
        }

     // Here is the main code of my controller


    }

}
```

This code works well, but out some function into a funvtion is a little weird no?

Where should i put these tools functions `get_inner_html` & `check_if_social_account`, in the `CompanyController` as private functions? In a separate files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this functions will be used in other class, extract it to another class. If not create private methods in your controller class.

Comment: No they will be used only in this Action

Comment: I will be trying extract this functions to methods. This will give you possibility to later potential refactor.

Comment: so create a new controller with these functions in here ?

Comment: If you use this functions only in `CompanyController` extract to methods in this controller. But if you know you will be using this on other controllers, extract it to separate class.